# Fraction to Mixed Number in String Format

Tags: decimal, division, fractions

My function should take a string, which is a basic `x/y` fraction, and convert that into a mixed fraction as a string, `a b/c` where `a` is an integer and `b/c` is an irreducible fraction.

Here is my code:

```
from fractions import Fraction
def mixed_fraction(s):
    s = x.numerator / y.denominator
    a = s 
    after_decimal = (a-int(a))[1:]
    dec_2_frac = Fraction(after_decimal) 
    b = b.numerator
    c = c.denominator
    if y > 0:
        return "{} {}/{}".format(a, b, c)
    else: 
        return "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"
```

Here is my error:

```
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Fundamentally, I can easily see how `x` is not defined properly, but I cannot wrap my head around how to denote x as corresponding numerator `x` of `x/y`. My senses tell me that I will need to go through the same debugging for `y`, thus I've attempted to define both on line 3. I'm simply stuck. Please help!

MJ

Answer (score 0):

```
from fractions import gcd

def mixed_fraction(s):
    a = s.split('/')
    x = float(a[0])
    y = float(a[1])
    if y == 0:
       return "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"
    z = (x/y)
    if z < 1:
       return s
    if z==int(z):
       return int(z)
    a = int(x) % int(y) 
    g = gcd(int(y), a)
    a = a / g
    y = y / g
    return "%s %s / %s" % (int(z), a, int(y))
```

Comment: This works! My next test case is saying "6/3" should equal output of 2, but I thought lines 12 and 13 account for this, no? My understanding is that this is accounted for in lines 12 and 13...my output right now is showing the right result but need the result to be 2 not '2'

Comment: Are you saying you are getting a string instead of a number for your result?

Comment: it's saying it should be a string, not an integer.

Comment: If you want a string change `return int(z)` to `return str(z)`

Comment: when i change it, it indicates it's a string of course, but now my output is a floating number string, '2.0'

Comment: lol, z is a float so yes it would be '2.0', apologies use `return str(int(z))`

Comment: You could also do `return "%s" % int(z)`